# Redirecting cloud pages and passing values

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I have customer data in a Data Extension. 
I am sending an email to the customers where there is a link to a cloudpage.

When the user clicks a cloud page link...he is redirected to the cloudpage where there is a feedback form.  The feedback form must have pre-populated data in some of the fields.  How do I pre populate the fields.

Can anyone give me an example?

Answer (score 3):

You can use CloudPagesURL to pass variables to a CloudPage. The link is built like this, where you can pass an arbitrary number of parameters:

```
<p>
<a title="Some page" 
href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(123,'VariableX',@X,’VariableY’,@Y))=%%" 
alias="Some page">
Click to go there
</a>
</p>
```

You must replace 123 with the ID of your Cloud Page. 
You can find the CloudPageID under Page Properties:

[image: See CloudPage ID]

Within the Cloud Page, you should use the AttributeValue to get the parameters passed on from CloudPagesURL:

```
VAR @X
SET @X = AttributeValue("VariableX")
```

Comment: Hi Lukas, do you know if there are any reserved keywords for attributeValue? I have this approach in place but unfortunately only  one of three (the last) parameter of the cloudpagesurl function returns a value when i receive it via attributevalue. The parameters i set are called "language" and "country" and a value like "blabla". Only blabla returns a value when we set the cloudpagesurl like `CloudPagesURL(4404,'language',@customer_language,'country',@customer_country,'blabla',@blabla)`

Comment: and retrieve like this `set @customer_country = AttributeValue('country')
set @customer_language = AttributeValue('language')
set @blabla = AttributeValue('blabla')`

Answer (score 1):

MarketingCloud passes encrypted subscriber information through email links to CloudPages.  Should be in a `?qs=21381648t7qdg` format.  So, you can just retrieve the `subscriberkey` from that encrypted string via ampscript at the top of your CloudPage

Here's a starting example:

```
 /* Get the Id of the account */ set @mid = [memberid]

 /* Get the key */ set @subKey = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey") /*if
 empty, pull from different param in URL*/ if empty(@subKey) then set
 @subKey = AttributeValue("sk") endif /*if empty, pull from form
 field*/ if empty(@subKey) then set @subKey =
 requestparameter("_subscriberkey")  endif

 /*Set the Data Extension in MC*/ set @de = 'Preference_Center'
```

Comment: Actually I prefer using [CloudPagesURL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm) in this scenario, since all the parameters (including SubscriberKey) are passed "behind the scenes" and hence hidden from the recipient.

Comment: how to use cloud pages url...can you give me an example??